# Removing a checked property

Tags: jquery

In the jQuery documentation, it says

> Do not use removeProp to remove
>   native properties such as checked,
>   disabled, or selected. This will
>   remove the property completely and,
>   once removed, cannot be added again to
>   element. Use .prop() to set these
>   properties to false instead.

Q: Instead of:

```
$('input:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
```

I should I now use:

```
$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Use</strike>

```
$('input:checkbox').not(this).attr('checked', false);
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7586a/

**Update:** Seems like I didn't get the news about jQuery 1.6's `.prop()`. Looks like your code is right.

Comment: In your example, try clicking the checkbox a couple times, then clicking the button. jQuery changed the way `.attr()` works, though they're restoring some of the behavior in `1.6.1`.

Comment: What about: $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop({checked:false});

Comment: @patrick-dw - you're absolutely right. wasn't aware of this change. learning something new every day.. thanks! :)